# Waiting in for loop until QRadioButton get checked everytime?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a situation where i need to get Pass/Fail from tester for every test step in PySide GUI. Now the data of testsuite i am running in for loop and trying to get current checked/unchecked state of QRadioButton in for loop based on which i will do further code processing. 
My code is :-

```
for i in range(self.ui.hlfDataset_sa_lst.count()):

    self.ui.pass_radio.setChecked(False)
    self.ui.fail_radio.setChecked(False)

    print "command ", str(self.ui.hlfDataset_sa_lst.item(i).text())
    print "Run  ", str(i)+" is here"
    ##
    self.telnetThread = TelnetThread.SocketTunnel("localhost",2000)
    returnCommand = self.telnetThread.communicateSock(str(self.ui.hlfDataset_sa_lst.item(i).text()))
    print "returnCommand ",returnCommand
    ##XML Data structure
    result = ET.SubElement(results,"result")
    testcasestepno = ET.SubElement(result,"testcasestepno")
    testerComment = ET.SubElement(result,"testerComment")
    testresult = ET.SubElement(result,"testresult")
    mguImage = ET.SubElement(result,"mguImage")

    if self.ui.pass_radio.isChecked():
        print "TC passed "
        testcasestepno.text = str(i+1)
        testresult.text = "PASS"
        mguImage.text = "NA"
        testerComment.text=str(self.ui.testercomment_txt.text())
    elif self.ui.fail_radio.isChecked():
        if not str(self.ui.testercomment_txt.text()):
            QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Tester Comment ', 'Tester Comment is desired ', QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
            self.ui.pass_radio.setChecked(False)
            self.ui.fail_radio.setChecked(False)
        else:
            print "TC failed "
            testcasestepno.text = str(i+1)
            testresult.text = "FAIL"
            testerComment.text = str(self.ui.testercomment_txt.text())
            #Save Live Image when failed
```

I want for loop to wait until tester has provided the input and i don't want to put sleep or in anyway to use thread unless convenient way is shown.
This code runs complete loop without waiting for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to wait until one of buttons (`fail_radio` or `pass_radio`) is checked before `if self.ui.pass_radio.isChecked():` line.

In Qt, you can achieve this using QEventLoop like here:
[waiting for a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052192/waiting-for-a-signal), where signal you want to wait for is `clicked`. You need to connect both buttons' signals to `quit` slot before executing it. For signal/slot connecting in PyQt you can look here:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html

So you need to write something like:

```
loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
self.ui.fail_radio.clicked.connect(loop.quit)
self.ui.pass_radio.clicked.connect(loop.quit)
loop._exec()
```

Comment: The syntax for signal connection provided in the PyQt5 example also works for PyQt4 since version 4.5. It is very unlikely anyone is using a version of PyQt4 older than 4.5 (v4.5 was released over 7 years ago!). The "new style" syntax is thus preferred for PyQt4 examples as well! See [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) for more details.

Comment: @three_pineapples, thank you for clarification, I'm using Qt and Python separately so I didn't know that...

Comment: Thanks for the respone, i getting Encountered "exec" at line 176, column 14. Was expecting:     <NAME> ...   at loop.exec()

Comment: Okay, its loop._exec()

Comment: @PawankumarDubey, heh, sorry

Comment: It worked like charm, i just have to call _exec() in for loop. Thanks i am not able to write you name. :)

Comment: @ukrkyi Stuck with this, do you have any answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804580/unable-to-click-on-qradiobutton-after-linking-it-with-qtcore-qeventloop