# Use QNetworkRequest in another class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a get_curl () method in the mainWindow class.  I want to move this method into a separate class so that it can be used from any part of the program.  i tried to do this but nothing worked.  I understand that the problem is in the connect () that I used in my Utils class.  I need that I can call a method the same method get_curl () but from my Utils class

And i delete some of my code

**MainWindow.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include <qstackedwidget.h>
#include <qstatusbar.h>

#include <qstring.h>

#include <qdebug.h>
#include <qtextcodec.h>
#include <qvariant.h>

#include <QtNetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.h>
#include <QtNetwork/qnetworkrequest.h>
#include <QtNetwork/qnetworkreply.h>



class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;

    QNetworkAccessManager* manager;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkReply* reply;

    QString contents;
    QString err;

    void get_curl();
    void set_btn_clicks();

private slots:
    void on_btn();

    void on_btnRmouteClicked();



    void slott(QNetworkReply*);
};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include "Utils.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    
    set_btn_clicks();   
}

void MainWindow::set_btn_clicks()
{      
    connect(ui.btnRemoute, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_btnRmouteClicked()));
    
}//MENU BTN CLICKS

#pragma region Engine
void MainWindow::get_curl()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://auth.pentagon.com/api/client/account"));
    request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/json"));
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");


    reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(slott(QNetworkReply*)));
}
void MainWindow::slott(QNetworkReply*)
{
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        contents = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
        qDebug() << contents;
    }
    else
    {
        err = reply->errorString();
        qDebug() << err;
    }
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region BtnClicks
void MainWindow::on_btn()
{
    get_curl();
}

void MainWindow::on_btnRmouteClicked()
{
    get_curl();
    Utils u;
    u.print_curl();
    ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui.pageRemoute);
}

#pragma endregion
```

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: can you rephrase your problem, right now your question is unclear?

Comment: unrelated: the SIGNAL and SLOT syntax is not the preferred approach of binding. You should use the Qt5-style connections instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [waiting for a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052192/waiting-for-a-signal)

Answer (score 1):

Connect the `finished` signal to a C++ lambda that is passed in from outside.
This is only possible using the new connection syntax:

```
using url_cb = std::function<void(QNetworkReply*)>;
void url_get(QNetworkRequest request, url_cb cb) {
    auto manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, manager, &QObject::deleteLater);
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, manager, cb);
    manager->get(request);
}
```

You can then rewrite `MainWindow::on_btnRmouteClicked()` as follows:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnRmouteClicked() {
    QNetworkAccessRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://auth.pentagon.com/api/client/account"));
    request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/json"));
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");
    url_get(request, [=](QNetworkReply * rep) {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            contents = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
            qDebug() << contents;
        } else {
            err = reply->errorString();
            qDebug() << err;
        }

        Utils u;
        u.print_curl();
        ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui.pageRemoute);
    });
}
```

Comment: So, if i copy this code into another class, like  A { void H() {qnetwor acess...} Void J() {using url_cb...}};     can i call thouse code like A a; a.H();                   ???

Comment: The definitions of `url_get` and `url_cb` can live everywhere. Somewhere in a method of class A you would just call `url_get` with a callback.

Comment: I want to clarify.  i am new to c ++.  I need a separate class in which I can call the method for sending this curl request.  how should I write this method correctly.  did I put it right?

Comment: Why do you think you need a separate class? You can call this function anywhere you want.

Comment: mainWindow - iths my .ui class. I don't wat to have any "engine ligic" in this class. I don't know is it in qt bad or not, but in any way i dont wat. sry for a lot of "I", im bad in English

Comment: Okay, so create a separate class and instantiate it in your main window class. It's your code, you can do what you want :-)

Comment: omg. i so stupid. im sorry. can u publish ready-to-use code? if it's not difficult for you, I need a ready-made class (.h & .cpp) in which there will be 1 public method. let's call it class A. I want to call method () which just returns something to me that I get from the server (I just get a string). If necessary, I can upload the project to git. All code for this wirks should be in class A, if it possible

Comment: That is a *completely different question*!